# Contents in a grid cannot be shown correctly

Tags: html, css

I've finished to divide each part of layouts with grid. But the contents (including the elements and the nesting elements inside) cannot be shown at the correct position (between nav and footer) when I debugged the HTML and CSS code which will be shown below:

```css
article {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 20vh 10vh auto 10vh;
    grid-template-columns: 10vw 20vw 20vw 20vw 20vw 10vw;
    grid-template-areas: ". header header header header ."
    ". nav nav nav nav ."
    ". section section section section ."
    ". footer footer footer footer ."
}
header { 
    grid-area: header; 
    background-color: whitesmoke; 
    position: fixed;
}
nav { 
    grid-area: nav; 
    background-color:lightskyblue; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0ex;
    right: 0ex;
    background-color: lightskyblue;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Kanit;
}
section { 
    grid-area: content; 
    background-color: whitesmoke; 
}
footer { grid-area: footer; background-color: lightskyblue; }

div.pi{
    width: 60vh;
    height: 40vh;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Ubuntu;
}
h1{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Introduce Myself</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexDemo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <article>
            <header> </header>
            <nav>
                <a class="guilding" href="#P2">Personal Information & Career Goal</a>
                <a class="guilding" href="#P3">Education</a>
                <a class="guilding" href="#P4">Work Experience & Placements</a>
                <a class="guilding" href="#P5">Skills</a>
                <a class="guilding" href="#P6">Hobbies & Interests & Achievements</a>
            </nav>
            <section> 
                <div class="pi">
                    <h1 id="#P2">Personal Information</h1>
                    <p>concrete contents
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="photo">

                </div>
                <div class="pic">

                </div>
                <div class="cg">

                </div>
                <div id="#P5">

                </div>
            </section>
            <footer> </footer>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why It happened and ask for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change

```
section {
  grid-area: content;    <---- content is not one of your grid-areas
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

to

```
section {
  grid-area: section;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Your header still needs to be fixed to the top but I'll leave you to that.

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20vh 10vh auto 10vh;
  grid-template-columns: 10vw 20vw 20vw 20vw 20vw 10vw;
  grid-template-areas: ". header header header header ." ". nav nav nav nav ." ". section section section section ." ". footer footer footer footer ."
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: fixed;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0ex;
  right: 0ex;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Kanit;
}

section {
  grid-area: section;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

div.pi {
  width: 60vh;
  height: 40vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Introduce Myself</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexDemo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <header>test</header>
    <nav>
      <a class="guilding" href="#P2">Personal Information & Career Goal</a>
      <a class="guilding" href="#P3">Education</a>
      <a class="guilding" href="#P4">Work Experience & Placements</a>
      <a class="guilding" href="#P5">Skills</a>
      <a class="guilding" href="#P6">Hobbies & Interests & Achievements</a>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <div class="pi">
        <h1 id="#P2">Personal Information</h1>
        <p>concrete contents
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="photo">
        <h1 id="#P2">Personal Information</h1>
        <p>concrete contents
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="pic">
        <h1 id="#P2">Personal Information</h1>
        <p>concrete contents
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="cg">
        <h1 id="#P2">Personal Information</h1>
        <p>concrete contents
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="#P5">
        <h1 id="#P2">Personal Information</h1>
        <p>concrete contents
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer> </footer>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```